Do I need to have insulation on all walls of the basement before finishing?
I'm buying a house in Northern Virginia with an unfinished section of basement. Parts of the walls do not have insulation. Should everything be insulated before finishing this section?



Location is important.  Insulation in basements is needed at the top and less below the frost line.  Insulation mainly for your comfort and heating/cooling efficiently.

Thanks. I edited to include location (Northern Virginia).

Find your local frost line.  The ground below that should stay close to 50F, so less insulation needed than above with temps below 32F.  Vapour barrier is probably more important, than your comfort level.

Even if you don't have to insulate below the frost line (probably about 24" in your area), you might as well insulate the whole wall.
